# How charge conjugation operator flips chirality

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, chirality, charge-conjugation

I am trying to understand the charge conjugation operator by reading several references online. Until I come to a point which mention that using the anticommutation properties of the Dirac-$\gamma$ matrices, we can see that when $C$ acting on a chiral field, it will flips its chirality.
But I still cannot see it clearly. I'm going with this step
$$ \left\{C,\gamma^5\right\}=i\left(\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^5+\gamma^5\gamma^2\gamma^0\right)=0\\
i\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^5=-i\gamma^5\gamma^2\gamma^0\\
C\gamma^5=-\gamma^5C $$
Anyone can elaborate more?

Comment: You are in the [Majorana representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Majorana_basis)? C behaves very differently in different representations.

Comment: I think I am adopting the Weyl representation of Dirac $\gamma$-matrices, and express the spinor field $\psi(x)$ in term of two distinct Weyl spinor $\chi$ and $\phi$.

Comment: In the Weyl, as in the Dirac representation, C is real antisymmetric and $\gamma_5$ is real symmetric, and the two commute.

Comment: So your expressions are plain wrong. What's your point?  Review [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-symmetry#Charge_conjugation_in_the_chiral_basis).